# reload UIwebview from tabBarItem

Tags: uiwebview, uitabbaritem

what i need is when someone clicked on tabBarItem 0 it will reload the page

I have tabBarController in my AppDelegate.m file

my problem is how to call webview in MainView.m to reload

i use code to check which tabBarItem was clicked and its work fine

```
(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSLog(@"TabItem pressed");  

    if (viewController == [TabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]) {
        NSLog(@"Tab 1 was pressed");  


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out the problem, and if so, what was the solution? I really want to know how to pass a loadRequest to the viewController in this context...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reload data?

If you are, then you can put something like:

```
if (viewController == [TabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]) { 
NSLog(@"Tab 1 was pressed"); 
[self.webView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanx for replay

webView is in MainView.xib 
And am writing the code in 
MyappDelegate

self.webView  i get error
@K.Honda

Comment: i got this error " Property 'webView' not found on object of type 'MyAppDelegate *' "